# Need to recompile vite every time I push changes to the server

Tags: laravel, sass, vite

I am using Laravel 10 for a project, and it utilizes Vite for asset bundling.

Right now, I am using it to compile a SASS file and a JS file in my primary layout blade file:

```
@vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

However, it seems that every change I commit to the server, even if it is not a file that touches or uses my layout file, seems to require me to log into my server via SSH and run:

```
npm run build
```

before my application will display.

I feel like, in previous applications I've built, that use Vite, I only had to run the build command if I made changes to the CSS.

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

My package.json file looks like this. I have also tried adding "--watch" after "vite build"), to no avail.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.5",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "sass": "^1.67.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

and my vite.config.js file looks like this:

```
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
    import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

    export default defineConfig({
        plugins: [
            laravel({
                input: [
                    'resources/sass/app.scss',
                    'resources/js/app.js',
                ],
                refresh: true,
            }),
        ],
    });
```

These seem to mirror the other project I worked on that utilizes Vite exactly... so I'm not sure what else I might be missing.